What was the backdrop of the reference to Anti -Christ in 1 John 4?
We read in 1 Jn 4: 1-3 (KJV):

Beloved, believe not every spirit, but try the spirits whether they are of God: because many false prophets are gone out into the world.
Hereby know ye the Spirit of God: Every spirit that confesseth that Jesus Christ is come in the flesh is of God: And every spirit that confesseth not that Jesus Christ is come in the flesh is not of God: and this is that spirit of antichrist, whereof ye have heard that it should come; and even now already is it in the world.

Presumably, there were false prophets telling the early church members either against the historical existence of Jesus or against his divinity. What exactly was the backdrop of John's reference  to Anti -Christ ?

Can you clarify what you mean by "backdrop". Are you asking about what was happening in Jerusalem at that time that was causing John to consider it Antichrist?

We do not know.

This question cannot be answered from scripture itself. There are indications, generally, of the condition of the churches in Asia in the letters to the seven churches in Revelation. But not the specifics about which the question is inquiring.

Two chapters earlier, John described the same situation in 1 John 2:18–23 (NLT):

18 Dear children, the last hour is here. You have heard that the Antichrist is coming, and already many such antichrists have appeared. From this we know that the last hour has come.
19 These people left our churches, but they never really belonged with us; otherwise they would have stayed with us. When they left, it proved that they did not belong with us.
20 But you are not like that, for the Holy One has given you his Spirit, and all of you know the truth.
21 So I am writing to you not because you don’t know the truth but because you know the difference between truth and lies.
22 And who is a liar? Anyone who says that Jesus is not the Christ. Anyone who denies the Father and the Son is an antichrist.
23 Anyone who denies the Son doesn’t have the Father, either. But anyone who acknowledges the Son has the Father also.

Some people that had been members of the Church of God have separated themselves from the organization and are now teaching a different gospel under the name Christianity.
John again warns against these heretical false Christians in 2 John 1:7–10:

7 I say this because many deceivers have gone out into the world. They deny that Jesus Christ came in a real body. Such a person is a deceiver and an antichrist.
8 Watch out that you do not lose what we have worked so hard to achieve. Be diligent so that you receive your full reward.
9 Anyone who wanders away from this teaching has no relationship with God. But anyone who remains in the teaching of Christ has a relationship with both the Father and the Son.
10 If anyone comes to your meeting and does not teach the truth about Christ, don’t invite that person into your home or give any kind of encouragement.

Paul talks about the same thing in 2 Corinthians 11:3–15:

3 But I fear that somehow your pure and undivided devotion to Christ will be corrupted, just as Eve was deceived by the cunning ways of the serpent.
4 You happily put up with whatever anyone tells you, even if they preach a different Jesus than the one we preach, or a different kind of Spirit than the one you received, or a different kind of gospel than the one you believed.
…
12 But I will continue doing what I have always done. This will undercut those who are looking for an opportunity to boast that their work is just like ours.
13 These people are false apostles. They are deceitful workers who disguise themselves as apostles of Christ.
14 But I am not surprised! Even Satan disguises himself as an angel of light..
15 So it is no wonder that his servants also disguise themselves as servants of righteousness. In the end they will get the punishment their wicked deeds deserve.

And in Galatians 1:6–9:

6 I am shocked that you are turning away so soon from God, who called you to himself through the loving mercy of Christ. You are following a different way that pretends to be the Good News
7 but is not the Good News at all. You are being fooled by those who deliberately twist the truth concerning Christ.
8 Let God’s curse fall on anyone, including us or even an angel from heaven, who preaches a different kind of Good News than the one we preached to you.
9 I say again what we have said before: If anyone preaches any other Good News than the one you welcomed, let that person be cursed.

Jesus himself predicted this would happen in Mark 13:22:

For false messiahs and false prophets will rise up and perform signs and wonders so as to deceive, if possible, even God’s chosen ones.

And he revealed to John in Revelation 19:20 (and elsewhere) that at the end there would be single great false prophet:

And the beast was captured, and with him the false prophet who did mighty miracles on behalf of the beast — miracles that deceived all who had accepted the mark of the beast and who worshiped his statue.

This false prophet, with the aid of Satan, is "the one deceiving the whole world" (Revelation 12:9), except for those few true Christians that hold on to the original message.

The Epistle of Polycarp to the Philippians
Chapter VII.--Avoid the Docetae, and persevere in fasting and prayer.

"For whosoever does not confess that Jesus Christ has come in the flesh, is antichrist;" 1 and whosoever does not confess the testimony of the cross, 2 is of the devil; and whosoever perverts the oracles of the Lord to his own lusts, and says that there is neither a resurrection nor a judgment, he is the first-born of Satan. 3

1. 1 John iv. 3.  ↩
2. Literally, "the martyrdom of the cross," which some render, "His suffering on the cross." ↩
3. [The original, perhaps, of Eusebius (Hist. iv. cap. 14). It became a common-place expression in the Church.]
The reference to the "Antichrist" in 1 John 4 emerges within a theological and historical backdrop concerned with affirming the humanity and suffering of Jesus Christ against certain early heretical teachings. This context is illuminated by The Epistle of Polycarp to the Philippians, especially in Chapter VII, where Polycarp echoes themes from 1 John 4. Polycarp, a direct disciple of the Apostle John, warns the Philippians against the Docetists, who claimed that Jesus did not come in true human flesh. Polycarp explicitly states, “whosoever does not confess that Jesus Christ has come in the flesh, is antichrist.” This assertion highlights the early Church's defense against views that would invalidate the reality of Jesus’s physical incarnation and suffering, particularly Docetism, which denied the tangible human experience of Christ.
Polycarp’s reference to the “martyrdom of the cross” underscores a key belief shared with John: that Jesus’s suffering was real, embodied, and essential to His redemptive role. The denial of this suffering was not merely theological deviation but, according to both John and Polycarp, an affront that placed one in the realm of the “antichrist” spirit, a term John uses to identify teachings that contradict the gospel's core truths. For John, the “spirit of the antichrist” represented any influence that denied Jesus’s incarnation, reducing Him to a symbolic or purely spiritual figure, thus nullifying the salvific significance of His suffering and resurrection.
This heretical context likely influenced John's strong language in 1 John 4:3: “every spirit that does not confess Jesus is not from God; this is the spirit of the antichrist.” The backdrop here, as both John and Polycarp would assert, is that the reality of Jesus’s coming “in the flesh” is a foundational truth, and any denial of it constitutes a profound deviation from apostolic teaching.

@ Betho's Your answer highlights the really meaning of this topic. There are many false teachers who have "the spirit" of antichrist.  And 1 John defines what is meant by "antichrist." (1 John 4:3) All throughout the centuries the Church is confronted with such evil men...  The modern tendency for pastors to zero in on just one grand Antichrist  in an alleged "end times" misses the point of John.  (They forget that the Apocalypse is a different genre and should not be considered "prophecy" as such.)

Cultural BackdropThe cultural and theological backdrop for the writings of John are most readily available by reading the Ante-Nicene Fathers (the letters, dissertations, and writings of the Early Church disciples up to A.D. 325.)
From the get-go, the Church of Jesus was inundated with egotistical men who began sects based on their unique interpretations of Scripture and Christian theology. It didn't take long after---and during---the life of the Apostles for many heretical groups to sprout up like mushrooms in a virgin forest!
Some of these groups were Jewish (Judaizers, Acts 15). Some were Gentile pastors gone astray (see Philemon, Galatians 1). Others were pagans with a tendency to mix Christianity with pagan idolatry.
Jesus forewarned the disciples about this propensity of wicked men (Matthew 24, Mark 13:22); and we have record of Paul confronting these men (2 Corinthians 11:3-15, Galatians 1:6-7). From then on, heretics have been the bane and curse of the Church since the first century. Modern times have seen its share of them rising and doting the church landscape, leading thousands of unsuspecting disciples astray.
To better understand this backdrop, one merely need read Irenaeus Against Heresies (A.D. 120-202) [Ante-Nicene Fathers, Vol.1, pp. 309-567.] His several "books" demonstrate what the Apostle John was warning about: heresies that attacked the divinity of Jesus; sects that deviated from orthodoxy; men who had "the spirit of antichrist." And there were many of them, just as John noted---not just one major bad dude! (1 John 4:1-3)
